# Adding src/test/resources to classpath when using maven exec:java

Tags: xml, maven, classpath, exec

I am trying to execute some code that it is going to generate a test class (and be placed in src/test/java) which needs access to the src/test/resources folder. I am using maven exec:java (tried exec:exec) as well but with no luck.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Generate Derivation Test Cases Test</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                        <mainClass>com.etse.persistence.derivationtestcase.TestGenerator</mainClass>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>derivationTestCases</argument>
                            <argument>/common-application-context.xml</argument>
                            <argument>/persistence-application-context.xml</argument>
                            <argument>/math-application-context.xml</argument>
                            <argument>/persistence-derivationtestcase-context.xml</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

My question here is how/where do I place the {basedir}/src/test/resources so it is used in the classpath for the call to TestGenerator

Thanks

Juan

Answer (score -1):

You are binding very early with `generate-test-sources`, probably before the resources plugin can copy the `src/test/resources` folder into `target`. I would try pointing the `TestGenerator` to `src/test/resources` rather than trying to use the classpath.